# copy a List without reference in dart

Tags: list, dart

i have this code:

```
double determinant(List<dynamic> a) {


print(a);
  int n = a.length;
  List<dynamic> am = a.map((dynamic e) => e).toList();
  for (int fd = 0; fd < n; fd++) {
    for (int i = fd + 1; i < n; i++) {
      if (am[fd][fd] == 0) {
        am[fd][fd] = 1.0e-18;
      }
      var crScaler = am[i][fd] / am[fd][fd];
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        am[i][j] -= crScaler * am[fd][j];
      }
    }
  }
  double product = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    product *= am[i][i];
  }
  print(a);
  return product;
}
```

the first prints statement print a value , the second one prints a different one I think it is because of the reference in  "am".

for example:

```
final List<dynamic> a = [
[2.0, 3.0],
[1.0, 6.0]
```

];
determinant(a)

output:

```
[[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 6.0]]
[[2.0, 3.0], [0.0, 4.5]]
```

Comment: Please provide example of calling the method, the expected result and the currently wrong result your code are returning. Otherwise, it is hard to know for sure if a provided solution are correct for you.

Comment: Don't use `List<dynamic>`. If it's a `List<List<num>>` or `List<List<double>>`, type it at that. And yes, most likely you'd want to do `a.map((e) => e.toList()).toList()` to copy the inner lists too, if you don't want to change the original input.

Comment: still the same problem I think it is because of the lists in side the list

Answer (score 0):

the problem is coming from the lists inside the list this is how i solved it:
instead of:

```
List<dynamic> am = a.map((dynamic e) => e).toList();
```

do this:

```
List<List<double>> am = a.map((List<double> e) => e.map((e) => e).toList()).toList();
```